# How to execute a command using and log its output using logging.info in python

Tags: python, unix, logging

I want to execute a command and then log its output to a log file using logging.info

I am currently using

```
cmd = """var=$(cat ip.txt | head -1 | sed 's/[^|]//g' | awk '{ print length }')"""
logging.info(cmd)
process = os.popen(cmd)
processClose = process.close()


logging.info($var)
```

but it gives me an error as $ is an invalid syntax.

I want the output in the log file to print the value of the variable (var)

Answer (score 1):

The below method of execution works with logging.info

```
success = sp.call(cmd, stdout=open('temp_log', 'w'), stderr=open('temp_err_log', 'w'), shell = True)
outText = open('temp_log').readlines()
outText = ''.join(outText)
logging.info('Dump stderr:\n%s'%(outText))
```

Answer (score 0):

$var is invalid in your code.  It is invalid because the process space in which is was created is gone.

Try this:

```
    import subprocess
    cmd = "cat ip.txt | head -1 | sed 's/[^|]//g' | awk '{ print length }'"
    p = subprocess.Popen([cmd,], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    p.stdout.readline()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: problem is not with the execution of the script. I am not able to log the output in a file.
    cmd = """cat ip.txt | head -1 | sed 's/[^|]//g' | awk '{ print length }'"""
    logging.info(cmd)
    process = os.popen(cmd)
    processClose = process.close()

This works perfectly. I just want to use logging.info to see the output in a log file.